# My arrays are possibly causing the program to not enter loop?

Tags: rtc, neopixel

I'm working on a project to make a digital clock with an 8x32 ws2812 LED grid, arduino uno, and a RTC module.

Everything works great separately, but when I integrate it all together the code never seems to reach the loop function. I have print statements in the setup and start of the loop, and the setup statement triggers but the first print in the loop does not. Nothing in the loop seems to occur. Commenting out line by line I've identified that the problem somehow is caused by my arrays of neopixel locations. When I comment out lines that refer to certain arrays, the code works, all print statements are called and every other functionality works fine. When I restore the lines that call the problematic arrays and remove some of the values, it will eventually start working when I remove so many values from the end. Weird.

Array examples:

```
int left_min_zero[] = {145,146,147,148,149,150,153,166,169,170,171,172,173,174,161,158};
int left_min_one[] = {158,157,156,155,154,153};
int left_min_two[] = {145,158,161,174,173,172,171,164,155,148,149,150,153,166,169};
```

The full code is here: https://github.com/SupaTreadz/Pixel-Clock/blob/master/PixelClock.ino

The offending lines are related to the following arrays:

"left_min_four", "left_min_five", and all of the "right_min_" arrays (possibly, I only checked the first three)

ALL of the other arrays work fine. WHAT THE HECK IS GOING ON HERE???

Just to reiterate, those arrays worked perfectly before adding the clock stuff. So right now all of the hour digits function perfectly, the first digit of minutes work except for 4 and 5, and none of the right minute digits work.

Any insight into this problem that is driving me crazy would be much appreciated.

Comment: Post a working example. Tell exactly what line change the sketch operation.

Comment: Have you checked the memory status (build, run-time, etc)?

Comment: Just 256 LEDs and 402 numbers in those int arrays = ~1.572kB of memory. An Uno has only 2kB of memory.

Comment: The code linked has the problematic lines commented out and works, those lines are 317, 326, 339, 348, 357, 366, 375, 384, 393, 402, 411, 420. And the code uploads to the board fine, says it only uses 31% of program space and 54% of dynamic memory. Should I try a larger board?

Comment: It looks like a memory problem, and using the `String` class probably does not help...

Comment: Commenting out the Strings does not solve the problem. I will try a larger board I guess, but I don't understand how it can be a memory problem when the IDE says it has so much memory remaining?